# Tableau Rest Api special characters

Tags: api, character-encoding, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Rest API to retrieve the list of workbooks from Tableau Server and show the list on a webpage. The problem is that special characters in workbook names have invalid encoding (or at least encoding that I do not expect).

Name set in Tableau server web UI:

```
Book ó
```

Name retrieved from rest API:

```
Book Ã³
```

As far as I can tell this issue occured after we upgraded Tableau server to 2018.1.

Is there a way to specify the encoding in Tableau Rest API? Or determine the encoding used to store the workbook name in Tableau Server web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that after Tableau Server was updated to 2018.1 C# WebClient needs to have encoding set explicitly to UTF8 to handle special characters properly when querying Tableau REST API.